# In Python, is it possible to decorate both a class and non-class method with the same decorator?

Tags: python, arguments, closures, wrapper, decorator

I have a simple exception-logging decorator, which is handy for sending myself emails when my scripts throw exceptions.

```
def logExceptions(func):
   def wrapper():
      try:
         func()
      except Exception, e:
         logger.exception(e)

   return wrapper
```

However, if I want to decorate a class method, I have to modify wrapper() to take a 'self', otherwise I get the following error:

```
TypeError: wrapper() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Of course, at that point I can't use it to decorate any non-class methods, because then this error occurs:

```
TypeError: wrapper() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Is there a clean way to tackle this problem? Thank you =)

Comment: I recommend editing your question to use the more typical terms "function" and "method" (or "instance method") instead of "class method" and "non-class method". Using "class method" is confusing, because in Python a classmethod is a method that is decorated with the `@classmethod` decorator and takes the class itself (usually `cls`) rather than an instance (`self`) as its first argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual thing is to define your wrapper so it accepts `*args` and `**kwargs` and passes them on to the function it wraps.  This way it can wrap any function.

Also, I get the impression that what you are calling a "class method" is what Python calls an "instance method", and what you call "non-class method" is what Python calls a "function".  A "non-class method" (e.g., instance method) in Python takes a `self` argument.

Comment: Yeah, actually by class method OP may mean instance method or actual class method ("classmethod" decorator), and static method ("staticmethod" decorator) fits the second described behaviour. But in general it is hard to say, whether OP wanted to ask about instance method vs. standalone function, or instance/class method vs. static method.

Answer (score 5):

### Difference between instance method, `classmethod` and `staticmethod`

First a note: both static method and class method are also functions, so standard function rules mostly apply to them. I understand your question is about the difference between **static method** (which has no extra arguments passed) and **class method** (which receives class in the first argument):

```py
class Test(object):
    def standard_method(*args, **kwargs):
        # it is instance method (first argument will be instance)
        return args, kwargs

    @classmethod
    def class_method(*args, **kwargs):
        # it is class method (first argument will be class)
        return args, kwargs

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(*args, **kwargs):
        # it is static method (receives only arguments passed explicitly)
        return args, kwargs
```

The proof (or rather self-explanatory example) is here:

```py
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.standard_method()
((<__main__.Test object at 0x0000000002B47CC0>,), {})
>>> t.class_method()
((<class '__main__.Test'>,), {})
>>> t.static_method()
((), {})
```

As you see, the list of arguments passed differs depending on which type of method you choose. The problem you are facing is **variable number of arguments**.

### Solution

There is a solution for that - use argument unpacking:

```py
def some_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something here
        # args is a tuple with positional args, kwargs is dict with keyword args
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

After that, function returned by `some_decorator` will accept the same amount of arguments as decorated function.

So both these examples will work:

```py
@some_decorator
def say_hello():
    print 'hello'

@some_decorator
def say_something(something):
    print something
```

### Appendix

To give you fully complete example, it would be good if you would use such constructions (note usage of `functools.wraps`):

```py
from functools import wraps
def some_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something here
        # args is a tuple with positional args, kwargs is dict with keyword args
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

The reason for that is listed in [documentation for `functools.wraps()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps): it preserves function name and docstring, effectively resulting in the wrapper looking like a wrapped function (which is useful sometimes).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to decorating is use [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) which is a callback that operates on all uncaught exceptions to which you can assign your custom logging function. The benefit is that then you dont need to *mutilate* (and more importantly, keep track of) every function that you are interested in logging exceptions for.